# Get the created file ID - Google Drive API Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

Yesterday I implemented functionality to backup the data to Google Drive using a Flutter app. Everything worked correctly, except the part where I've to get the ID of the uploaded File.

This is the function which uploads a given File, situated at this path

```
Future<dynamic> gDriveFileCreator(googledrive.DriveApi drive,
      googledrive.File fileToUpload, String path) async {
    File file = File(path);
    fileToUpload.name = p.basename(file.absolute.path);
    var response = await drive.files.create(
      fileToUpload,
      uploadMedia: googledrive.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
    );
    return response;
  }
```

This is how I trigger this function :

```
responsePdfUpload =
              await gDriveFileCreator(drive, fileToUpload, pdfPath!);
```

Now, It works like a charm. My next requirement is to get the ID and store it in the local DB. However, when I try to get the ID from responsePdfUpload by doing : `responsePdfUpload.getId()`, It throws an exception stating "**Class 'File' has no instance method 'getId'**".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is there another way to get the ID from the File that google Drive returned ? As far as I know, the same method was working without any issues until yesterday.

I also debugged and I am indeed getting an id in the response.

[image]

Can somebody please help me here?

Comment: Surprisingly, responsePdfUpload.id worked here. It wasn't working yesterday. isn't this weird?

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<drive.File> _files = [];

  Future<void> _fetchFiles() async {
    print('fetchFiles called');
    try {
      var files = await _filesInFolder(driveFile);
      _files = files;
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error fetching files: $error");
    }
  }

  Future<List<drive.File>> _filesInFolder(drive.DriveApi driveApi) async {
    print('folder id:::::::::: $folderId');
    var res = await driveApi.files.list(
      spaces: 'drive',
      q: "'$folderId' in parents and trashed=false",
    );
    return res.files ?? [];
  }

// then 

          body: FutureBuilder(
                  future: _fetchFiles(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: _files.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var file = _files[index];
                          return Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Center(child: Text(file.name ?? '')),
                              subtitle: Text(file.id ?? ''),
                              trailing: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  print(file.id);
                                },
                                child: const Text('Print File ID'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  },
                )
```